axios error.response is undefined when CloudFlare turnstile returns 403
I have implemented CloudFlare turnstile so that when a certain API is called a 403 response is returned with an additional response header of cf-mitigated: challenge. I'm using axios to catch and print the error, this is my code
type IAxiosResponseErrorData = unknown
type IAxiosResponseErrorBody = unknown

const onResponseReject = (
  error: AxiosError<IAxiosResponseErrorData, IAxiosResponseErrorBody>
) => {
  console.log("error", error)
  
  // Do something if the error response has a certain header...

  return Promise.reject(error);
};

instance.interceptors.response.use(onResponseSuccess, onResponseReject)

export default instance

When I try to print error.response it logs undefined. Weird thing is that the network tab shows the header I'm looking for

What am I missing?
